# Minimal DFA: Number of states

Tags: formal-languages, automata, finite-automata

I am trying to solve a problem with regards to a DFA. What is the minimal number of states for the following language:

$$L:=\{x\in\{a,b\}^n\ \ | \ \ |x|_a=|x|_b\}$$

where $|x|_a$ denotes the amount of $a$'s in the word $x$. I have done some calculations and got $3\cdot2^{(n/2)}-1$. Is this the correct number of states?

Here is the DFA for $n=4$:
[image: DFA n=4]

Comment: Help yourself by proving your answer.

Comment: How did you arrive at this number and why do you doubt your result? "Verify my answer" questions are not a good fit for this site.

Comment: It's not hard to see which two states are equal.

Comment: Try enumerate each state by number of already read a's and b's. This must help.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. Your answer is plain wrong. First, it trivially does not work if $n$ is odd. But it is also wrong if $n$ is even (except for $n = 2$). Just compute the minimal automaton of $\{aabb,abab,abba,baab,baba,bbaa\}$ to be convinced. Your formula gives $3\cdot 2^2 - 1 = 11$ states but the minimal automaton only has $10$ states.

Comment: I have also added one for dead state ! And n cant be odd in this case because a and b both are equal

Comment: I also added one for dead state... Without it, the number of states would be 9.

Comment: Can you please show the diagram or tell me the software so that I can show mine .

Comment: No, you have to find by yourself.

Comment: I have added the DFA.

Comment: Your automaton is not minimal.